# How to force brew to install from local bottle (without git clone github.com/build/homebrew-deps)

Tags: macos, command-line, install, homebrew, python

My goal is the have brew skip trying to make calls to the Internet when installing local cached bottles.

I have downloaded the brew bottles for python and the python module virtualenv.

```
user@host ~ % ls
python-3.12.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
virtualenv-20-25.1.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
```

I've been successfully able to install the python bottle as follows

```
export HOMEBREW_VERBOSE=1
export HOMEBREW_DEBUG=1
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1

brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
brew install python-3.12.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
```

Unfortunately, when I then try to install virtualenv, it tries to `git clone github.com/build/homebrew-deps` and it fails

```
user@host ~ % brew install --ignore-dependencies --skip-cask-deps virtualenv-20-25.1.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromNameLoader): loading virtualenv
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromBottleLoader): loading build/deps/virtualenv-20-25.1.ventura.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/git --version
␛[34m==>␛[0m ␛[1mTapping build/deps␛[0m
git clone https://github.com/build/homebrew-deps /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/build/homebrew-deps --origin=origin --template= --config core.fsmonitor=false
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/build/homebrew-deps'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/build/homebrew-deps/': Failed to connect to example.com port 9999 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server
␛[31mError:␛[0m Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/build/homebrew-deps /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/build/homebrew-deps --origin=origin --template= --config core.fsmonitor=false` exited with 128.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/kernel.rb:244:in `safe_system'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/tap.rb:413:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/tap.rb:207:in `ensure_installed!'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:184:in `block in install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:177:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:177:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:91:in `public_send'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:91:in `<main>'
```

I don’t understand why Homebrew wants to clone the `homebrew-deps` repo, when I specifically told it to `--ignore-dependencies`.

In the end, how can I force it to stop trying to access the Internet?

Comment: Note: I've discovered that my installs work on homebrew v4.2.9 but fail on v4.2.15.